# How do I deal with my own revised solution of a provided answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

I asked a question that got a good answer. It solves my problem. However, it lacked some information and code to make it *the best* answer. I now have used this answer to create my own version, solving my own problem. However, it is extremely similar to the only and accepted answer on my question.

#### How can I share my own solution in the best possible way?

Do I create a new answer? (which would be a bit of a duplicate from the original answer), do I improve the answer that has been given to me (which is not the authors intent) or do I update my own question with the solution I currently use?

Comment: you are talking about this one I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679183/8620333 .. It's strange how I missed that one :p .. and yes his code can be optimised and reduced a lot

Comment: @TemaniAfif correct! But I didn’t want to induce the meta effect :)

Comment: well, you have only one question made last week. so with or without the link we can easily find it ;)

Comment: Well people are lazy I suppose hehe

Comment: now you have another anwser to consider :p

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you perceive it as an improvement of the original and without conflicting with the intent of the author, edit and leave a comment explaining it. Most people take kindly to such edits. However, if the author disagrees, respect their decision and don't go into an edit war. At this point post your version as a new answer if you think your version really warrants one.

Answer (score 47):

YMMV - Passer By's suggestion is fine enough. I tend to just post a new answer (after all, that's what the site is for - a question with multiple similar but different answers!).

For example:

> In the end, I used [Cris's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380268/how-do-i-deal-with-a-revised-solution-of-a-given-answer/380292?noredirect=1#comment670992_380292), after fooing the bar and bazzing the frobulator.
>
> I also found that, in this case, due to discombobulation, the following additional steps were required to avoid conscious uncoupling:
>
> …

However, in the situation you describe, I would probably not accept this new  answer. I'd accept the original, helpful answer and leave my own as a sort of addendum/erratum for future reference.

That being said, the decision on whether to accept the old answer or the new one that extends it, for me comes down to some nuances that depend a great deal on context (e.g. how far off the original answer was, how good it was, how important my addendum is for the general reader…).

Anyway, we can get bogged down with edit suggestions and comment threads but, ultimately, *this is a Q&A*: a series of questions and a series of answers. Don't be afraid to post answers. That's what we're all here for.

Comment: Indeed. And don’t forget to reference the answer you based your answer on.

Comment: Yep, that. Like: "In the end, I used [Cris's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380268/how-do-i-deal-with-a-revised-solution-of-a-given-answer/380292?noredirect=1#comment670992_380292), after fooing the bar and bazzing the frobulator. I also found that, in this case, due to discombobulation, the following additional steps were required to avoid conscious uncoupling: ...".

Comment: [YMMV](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ymmv) - your millage may vary.. lol @lazy humans.

Comment: @Sinatr do you not mean: '*laugh out loud at* lazy humans'?

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this answer is that one should properly cite sources. If the other answer was helpful and inspired your own solution, give credit to the author of the other answer - even if it is obvious where your inspiration came from.

Comment: @Polygnome Definitely. Thinking about it, I should edit my comment (which does say this) into the answer.

Comment: _"I would not accept my own answer"_ This is of course totally up to the OP, but personally, when I've answered and they come up with a better answer for themselves, I encourage them to accept their own answer, as a marker for later readers.

Comment: @Josh Mmm hard to reject that out of hand - for me it depends a great deal on context, how far off the original answer was, how good it was, how important my addendum is for the general reader... meh

Comment: Yup, definitely; I'm not disagreeing with you, just pointing out another consideration.

Comment: @Josh: Yep, thanks for it - have integrated

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. In the end, the question generated so much attention that a far greater answer than either my solution, or the initial solution ever was. I chose to accept this answer.