# Is there any way to provide feedback to editors from the suggested edit review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I just came across an edit where the only change was to correct a spelling error in the title of the post. From a quick read-through of the post there were no other changes necessary.

The thing is though: it wasn't a spelling error, it was simply a someone *correcting* "behavior" (American English) to "behaviour" (Commonwealth English).

While I'm sympathetic to the editor here as someone who's from a place where we all (or at least: most of us) speak and spell in Commonwealth English; I rejected the edit, but I wished I had some way to let them know *why* I was rejecting the edit without having to select "causes harm" (The edit doesn't cause harm, it's just unnecessary).

Is there a system already in place for this? Am I reading too much into the "causes harm" response?

The edit in question, hidden to limit the meta effect to some degree:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22239533

Comment: "Am I reading too much into the "causes harm" response?" You do. Use that to use a custom rejection message. There is nothing more to that. You can also link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/are-british-international-english-terms-acceptable-e-g-brackets-instead-of in that comment, if you like. (Click on the "share" link in the question to get a shorter URL)

Comment: @Tom Ok thanks. I was concerned that choosing "Causes harm" potentially counts towards some sort of additional penalty to the user who's really just trying to help. Always good to be sure :)

Comment: I would argue it does cause harm, by making several people review that question simply for an extra "u".

Comment: It looks like there was a "reason" to not give it a proper name: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356344/clarify-suggested-edit-rejection-reasons-by-changing-causes-harm-to-custom-re

Comment: Sometimes I wish reviewers could notify other reviewers that their review was incorrect, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22239390) this should have been posted as a new answer not an edit to the existing one

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I've seen meta posts on both sides of this, for example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380268/how-do-i-deal-with-my-own-revised-solution-of-a-provided-answer?cb=1 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324333/how-to-deal-with-software-updates-making-answers-out-of-date?rq=1 - the community does not seem to have an established rule afaict